# Submit html form without page refresh show on html page a success message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know this has been asked before and I'm sorry to ask. I've have searched through and am unable to find a way to get this to work.
I am trying to figure out how to incorporate a success message on the html form after submitting without a page refresh.
This code works fine and writes to the database except for the addition of the ajax code which it where my issue is. I freely admit to having limited knowledge with Ajax. Any help would be kindly appreciated - Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
  /* Honey Pot: */
  .robotic { display: none; }  
</style>
 
 
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<!-- <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="result22.php"> -->
  <p>
    <input name="dealershipname" type="text" id="dealershipname" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="Dealership Name" required />
  </p>
    <p>
    <input name="currentlycarry" type="text" id="currentlycarry" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="Manufactures You Currently Carry" required />
  </p>
    <p><label>Which Vehicles are you looking to Carry?</label><br>
  <select required="required" name="vehicletype" id="vehicletype" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" />
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="Vans">Vans</option>
  <option value="Pick Up Trucks">Pick Up Trucks</option>
  <option value="SUV">SUV</option>
  <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
  <option value="Combination of Vehicles">Combination of Vehicles</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="First Name" required />
  </p>
  <p>  
    <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="Last Name" required />
  </p>
    <p>  
    <input name="streetaddress" type="text" id="streetaddress" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="Street Address" required />
  </p>
      <p>  
    <input name="city" type="text" id="city" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="City" required />
  </p>
  <p>
  <select required="required" name="state" id="state" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" />
  <option value="">Select Your State</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
  <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
  <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
  <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
  <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
  <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
  <option value="MT">Montana</option>
  <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
  <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</p>  
  <p>
    <input name="zipcode" type="text" id="zipcode" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="Zip Code" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="Your Email Address" required />
  </p>
  <p>
 <textarea rows="5"  name="additionalinfo" id="additionalinfo" style="background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #b6b6b6; border-radius: 10px !important; color: #000; padding: 5px; width: 100% !important;" placeholder="Additional Information" /></textarea> 
  </p> 
<p class="robotic" id="pot"><input name="robotest" type="text" id="robotest" class="robotest" /></p>
   <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" style="background: #ff0000 none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 10px !important; font-size: 20px; color: #fff; padding: 1px 17px;" value="Send Info!" />
  </p>
</form>

<div id="contactResponse"></div>

<script>
     $("#form1").submit(function(event) 
     {
         /* stop form from submitting normally */
         event.preventDefault();

         /* get some values from elements on the page: */
         var $form1 = $( this ),
             $submit = $form1.find( 'submit[type="submit"]' ),
             dealershipname_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="dealershipname"]' ).val(),
             currentlycarry_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="currentlycarry"]' ).val(),
             vehicletype_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="vehicletype"]' ).val(),
             firstname_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="firstname"]' ).val(),
             lastname_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="lastname"]' ).val(),
             streetaddress_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="streetaddress"]' ).val(),
             city_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="city"]' ).val(),
             state_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="state"]' ).val(),
             zipcode_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="zipcode"]' ).val(),
             phone_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="phone"]' ).val(),
             email_value = $form1.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),    
             additionalinfo_value = $form1.find( 'textarea[name="additionalinfo"]' ).val(),
             url = $form1.attr('action');

         /* Send the data using post */
         var posting = $.post( url, { 
                           dealershipname: dealershipname_value, 
                           currentlycarry: currentlycarry_value, 
                           vehicletype: vehicletype_value, 
                           firstname: firstname_value, 
                           lastname: lastname_value, 
                           streetaddress: streetaddress_value, 
                           city: city_value, 
                           state: state_value, 
                           zipcode: zipcode_value, 
                           phone: phone_value, 
                           email: email_value, 
                           additionalinfo: additionalinfo_value          
                       });

         posting.done(function( data )
         {
             /* Put the results in a div */
             $( "#contactResponse" ).html(data);
         });
    });
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

and the php code:

```html
<?php
# ----------------------------------------------------
# ---- result22.php
# ----------------------------------------------------
// Receiving variables from form
@$dfw_ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
@$dealershipname = addslashes($_POST['dealershipname']);
@$currentlycarry = addslashes($_POST['currentlycarry']);
@$vehicletype = addslashes($_POST['vehicletype']);
@$firstname = addslashes($_POST['firstname']);
@$lastname = addslashes($_POST['lastname']);
@$streetaddress = addslashes($_POST['streetaddress']);
@$city = addslashes($_POST['city']);
@$state = addslashes($_POST['state']);
@$zipcode = addslashes($_POST['zipcode']);
@$phone = addslashes($_POST['phone']);
@$email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
@$additionalinfo = addslashes($_POST['additionalinfo']);
// @$robotest = addslashes($_POST['robotest']);
// @$xxxx = addslashes($_POST['xxxx']);


// Validation
//Sending Email to form owner
$dfw_header = "From: $email\n"
  . "Reply-To: $email\n";
$dfw_subject = "Message from redoform22 form Page";
// $dfw_email_to = "xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxx.com,xxxxxxxxxx@cccccccccc.com";
$dfw_email_to = "root@localhost";
$dfw_message = "Visitor's IP: $dfw_ip\n"
. "Dealership Name: $dealershipname\n"
. "Currently Carry: $currentlycarry\n"
. "Vehicle Type: $vehicletype\n"
. "First Name: $firstname\n"
. "Last Name: $lastname\n"
. "Street Address: $streetaddress\n"
. "City: $city\n"
. "State: $state\n"
. "Zip Code: $zipcode\n"
. "Phone: $phone\n"
. "Email: $email\n"
. "Additional Info: $additionalinfo\n";
// . "robotest: $robotest\n";
@mail($dfw_email_to, $dfw_subject ,$dfw_message ,$dfw_header ) ;

//Sending auto respond Email to visitor
$dfw_header = "From: root@localhost\n"
  . "Reply-To: root@localhost\n";
$dfw_subject = "Thank You for contacting redoform22";
$dfw_email_to = "$email";
$dfw_message = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
</head>
<body> html thank you message to person that filled out the form would go here</body>
</html>";
///////////
$dfw_header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$dfw_header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

@mail($dfw_email_to, $dfw_subject ,$dfw_message ,$dfw_header ) ;

//////////
if ($_POST) {
 $robotest = $_POST['robotest'];
  if ($robotest) {
    $error = "Bad Form.";                  // formerly robot msg
  }
}
//if there was  an error, return
if ($error) {
  @ob_end_clean();                      // clean out buffer, nothing there now
  exit($error);                        // exit, displaying error msg
}
/////////////////

// start connect to the database ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
//include db config file
@require_once 'db_config.php';
// end connect to the database ||||||||||||||||||||||||||

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// start saving record to the MYSQL database ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
@$dfw_strQuery = "INSERT INTO `redoform22table`(`dealershipname`,`currentlycarry`,`vehicletype`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`streetaddress`,`city`,`state`,`zipcode`,`phone`,`email`,`additionalinfo`)VALUES (\"$dealershipname\",\"$currentlycarry\",\"$vehicletype\",\"$firstname\",\"$lastname\",\"$streetaddress\",\"$city\",\"$state\",\"$zipcode\",\"$phone\",\"$email\",\"$additionalinfo\")" ;
// end saving record to the MYSQL database ||||||||||||||||||||||||||

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//start yields Update
@$dfw_strQueryUpdate = "UPDATE redoform22table SET `firstname`=\"$firstname\",`lastname`=\"$lastname\",`streetaddress`=\"$streetaddress\",`city`=\"$city\",`state`=\"$state\",`zipcode`=\"$zipcode\",`phone`=\"$phone\",`dealershipname`=\"$dealershipname\",`currentlycarry`=\"$currentlycarry\",`vehicletype`=\"$vehicletype\",`additionalinfo`=\"$additionalinfo\" WHERE (`email`=\"$email\")";
//end yields Update

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// start check to see if an entry exists for this email ||||||||||||||||||
@$dfw_strQueryEmail = "SELECT email FROM redoform22table WHERE email = \"$email\" ";
//end check to see if an entry exists for this email ||||||||||||||||||

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//start connect to the DB ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
$dfw_link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pw);
if (!$dfw_link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$dfw_db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $dfw_link);
if (!$dfw_db_selected) {
  die ('Can not use $dfw_db : ' . mysql_error());
}
//end connect to the DB ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// start see if it should be an update or an insert ||||||||||||||||||||||||
$dfw_result = mysql_query($dfw_strQueryEmail);
if (!$dfw_result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); //a failure, scram
} else {
  //the query worked, verify it's the same as the incoming email
  $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dfw_result);
  if ($row1["email"] != $email) {
    //email doesn't exist, insert new record
    $dfw_result = mysql_query($dfw_strQuery);        // insert row
    if (!$dfw_result) {
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
  } else {
    //update the existing record
    $dfw_result = mysql_query($dfw_strQueryUpdate);      // update existing row
    if (!$dfw_result) {
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
  }
}
//end see if it should be an update or an insert ||||||||||||||||||||||||

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ob_end_flush;                          // send form on to user
mysql_close($dfw_link);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// start send to page if it ran this far
// header("Location: http://example.com/" );
// end send to page if it ran this far
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// start OR just echo a message
// echo("<p align='center'><font face='Arial' size='3' color='#FF0000'>cool it sent</font></p>");
// end OR just echo a message

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a button instead of an input tag for the sendInfo. And add a click event listener on the button to trigger the function to do u r submit. This should stop the page from automatically being refreshed.

```
<button id="submit"> Send Info </button>

$('#submit').on('click',function(event){ //Do your functionality here ..... });
```

Comment: Kind Thanks Chait - made your suggested adjustments / changes and tried it with no success. IF I pull that ajax code out all together it works like a champ ending on the php page of course --where I CAN direct it or echo something. I may need to be satisfied with that.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML is no action defined for your form1, but in the JS part, you are defining `url = $form1.attr('action');` (which is empty) Thus your post will go to an empty url.

As you say `event.preventDefault();` this will not be called and you can still write the URL into the action field. You should btw do this, for compatibility, when the user has no JS enabled ;)

One sidenote for your PHP part: Use prepared statements and never call SQL querys mixed with input like this.

Comment: I will look into your suggestions for the ajax part Fabian N